# kendogrid update not being called

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am facing trouble in mvc c# kendo ui grid. i am trying to call the controller action from kendo update batch update method  i am having problem My mvc view is like this .It work fine on calling 'read' but while updating(saving all batch) then it is not hitting in controller:

```
   @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.oldList)
          .Name("grid")
          .Columns(columns =>
          {
              columns.Bound(m => m.IsNewString).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center;" }).Title("Data").Encoded(false).Width(80); ;
              columns.Bound(m => m.Id).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center;" }).Title("Code").Encoded(false).Width(80);
              columns.Bound(m => m.Name).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center;" }).Title("Business Name").Encoded(false).Width(80);
              columns.Bound(m => m.Address.Address1).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center;" }).Title("Address1").Encoded(false).Width(80);
              columns.Bound(m => m.Address.Address2).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center;" }).Title("Address2").Encoded(false).Width(80);
              columns.Bound(m => m.Address.Country).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center;" }).Title("Country").Encoded(false).Width(80);
              columns.Command(commands =>
              {
                  commands.Destroy(); 
              }).Title("Commands").Width(200);
          })
          .ToolBar(toolbar =>
          {
              //toolbar.Create(); 
              toolbar.Save(); 
          })
          .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell)) 
          .DataSource(dataSource =>
              dataSource.Ajax()
                .Batch(true) // Enable batch updates
                .Model(model =>
                {
                    model.Id(m => m.Id); 
                    model.Field(m => m.Id).Editable(false); 
                })
                //.Create(create => create.Action("Products_Create", "Home"))
                .Read(read => read.Action("LoadCompareList", "Home", new { clientId = clientid, templateId = templateid })) 
                                .Update(update => update.Action("test", "Home"))  

          )
          .Pageable()
                    )
```

My controller action is like this :

```
     [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult test([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request,IEnumerable<DetailsDTO> products)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

But this action is not firing. I don't know what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue and after struggling with it for a whole night, I realized that kendo requires that the model.Id value be present and unique. In my case this wasn't true because I was manually populating the grid from code (not from db), so I used another property that is guaranteed to have unique values as Id, and it worked.

```
Model(model =>
      {
        model.Id(x => x.MetreId);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

changing

```
.Update(update => update.Action("test", "Home"))
```

to

```
.Update(update => update.Action("test", "Home").Type(HttpVerbs.Post))
```

does the trick in my application. Also i'm using the attribute

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
```

in my controller.

Addition:

An other reason could be the model. I had to change my method to something like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> UpdatePackageList([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, [Bind(Prefix = "models")]IEnumerable<MyClass> products)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your Controller method to be:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult test([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, [Bind(Prefix = "models")] IEnumerable<DetailsDTO> products)
{
        return View();
}
```

Also ensure that you have referenced the script `kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js`

Comment: Yes thanks to you all. there while Savechanges button of kendo batch grid is clicked, it is hitting create action rather than update action. is create and update action are different in case of kendo batch grid? please make me know it. Thanks
 .Create(create => create.Action("create", "Location")) // Action method invoked when the user saves a new data item
                .Update(update => update.Action("update", "Location"))  // Action method invoked when the user saves an updated data item

Comment: Had the same issue and thought I was loosing my mind.  The Grid Update and Delete methods were calling the Create method.  When I removed the Create method, nothing was being called on update and delete.  See answer below for help.  My model.Id was not the same in my viewmodel which was bound to the grid and my entity.  Wasted hours on this.